# why md-select does not get populated with angular?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, material-design

I am using material select in my application, it worked with normal select when i use bootstrap. what is the issue here?. Here is the code,

**HTML:**

```
<md-select ng-model="widget.chartConfig.options.chart.type" >
        <md-option ng-value="t.title" data-ng-repeat="t in widget.chartTypes">{{ t.title }}</md-option>
</md-select>
```

**App.js:**

```
var app = angular.module('DemoApp', ['ngMaterial']);    
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.widget = [];
    $scope.widget.push(    
  {
     chartTypes:[
  {"id": "line", "title": "Line"},
  {"id": "spline", "title": "Smooth line"},
  {"id": "area", "title": "Area"},
  {"id": "areaspline", "title": "Smooth area"},
  {"id": "column", "title": "Column"},
  {"id": "bar", "title": "Bar"},
  {"id": "pie", "title": "Pie"},
  {"id": "scatter", "title": "Scatter"}
  ],
   chartConfig : {
    options: {
      chart: {         
        type:  "bar"
      }
  }
  }
  }
  );
});
```

Here is the [`Plunker`](http://plnkr.co/edit/Wzjb0Ldet5dAoD6qz0UZ?p=preview);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

widget is any array. 
You need to replace `widget` with `widget[0]`
Here is the updated plunker. http://plnkr.co/edit/MxfwsFafIky2L7VZguAE?p=preview

Answer (score 1):

You were missed to refer widget index `widget` ti `widget[0]` in both places

**HTML**

```
<md-select ng-model="widget[0].chartConfig.options.chart.type" >
        <md-option ng-value="t.title" data-ng-repeat="t in widget[0].chartTypes">{{ t.title }}</md-option>
</md-select>
```

[**Working Plukr**](http://plnkr.co/edit/22ZbQZES62n4oqyf3cNO?p=info)

Comment: @Sajeetharan Mistake are always make by man :p otherewise we will be GOD :D